# About ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

Such as I get a  filter model:

```
public class  Filter
{
   public int  Id{get;set;}
   public  string Name{get;set;}
  public  DateTime CreateTime{get;set;}
}
```

And there is a SearchController  action like:

```
public  ActionResult  Search(Filter  filterModel)
{
      List<Model>  model =SampleBll.get(filterModel)
}
```

so the  question is.How to configure  URL like

```
/Search/{Filter.Id}_{Filter.Name}_{Filter.CreatTime}/
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat `{Filter.Id}_{Filter.Name}_{Filter.CreatTime}` as `string filter` and parse it in your controller.

```
public ActionResult Search(string filter)
{
   var parts = filter.Split("|".ToCharArray());

   Filter model = new Filter();
   model.Id = Int32.Parse(parts[0]);

   // ...
}
```

Comment: The answer by Stephen Lloyd should really by the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

You would first need to add the following route into your Global.asax.cs `RegisterRoutes` method, **before** the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search", // Name
    "Search/{Id}_{Name}_{CreateTime}", // url format
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Search" } // Defaults
    );
```

Once this is done, going to your application using a url such as `/Search/123_Test_06-01-2011` would trigger the route, and the built-in object mapping will take care of mapping the properties to the model as long as the parameter names in the route match the names of the property and they can be successfully cast to the corresponding type.

Answer (score 0):

Use string or change _ per / `{Filter.Id}/{Filter.Name}/{Filter.CreatTime}`

Comment: what is the difference between **Id_Name** and **Id/Name** in terms of route mapping possibilities?

Comment: Id_Name is a string Id/Name is two parts of a url. The routting won´t split strings, just take parts of url and put into variables

Comment: I don't think so.. In a URL pattern, you define placeholders by enclosing them in braces ( { and } ). You can define more than one placeholder in a segment, but they must be separated by a literal value. For example, {language}-{country}/{action} is a valid route pattern. [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)